# Visual Studio output directory when building a WCF project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a vs2010 solution which contains a dozen projects. One of those projects is a class library containing WCF services which are used by another project serving as the client(start-up project).
The WCF project has it's output build directory set to `\bin` for `all configurations` and `any cpu`.
Problem is when I do a debug build, it seems that all dll's go to `\bin\Debug` and **only some of them** go to `\bin`. 
e.g. the WCF services Dll does not appear in `\bin`, only in `\bin\Debug`.
These causes the visual studio host not to find the necessary dll's and thus making my WCF services unreachable.

I've searched the high and lows to make this work but keep being stuck on this weird VS behavior.
Why won't VS output all dll's to `\bin` like it's set to in the project properties ? 
And why does it keep creating a `debug` folder in `\bin` while all output just should go to `\bin` ?

It would be great if anyone could shine a light on this.

Comment: Have you double checked that the output path setting in `Debug` configuration of your WCF project is set to `bin` as well? It may be overridden.

Comment: Yes double checked and output path is definitely set to \bin